# Using an API to go shopping on other people's shopify website

Tags: php, shopify

I am a frequent shopper at various shopify websites.

So much so, that I'd like to write a program to shop for me. That is, it generates a shopping list (I know how to do that part) and then places those items into the cart for me. It should then direct me to my cart so I can pay for the items by normal means.

I'm coding in PHP/javascript (I'd prefer a PHP solution). I know my way around cURL, and I'm pretty good at figuring out API docs if I can find them.

So, how do I add items to cart?

Comment: https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart

Comment: @nice_dev I did find that document, but I thought I was looking at how to access my own website from the backend. So I can use that do access someone else's website as a customer? I'd better give that doc another read. Thank you.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679346/how-to-add-items-to-the-cart-using-the-shopify-api) should be helpful then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here: https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/cart-use-permalinks-to-pre-load-the-cart/td-p/613702

Note, you don't need any credentials whatsoever to be able to use this feature. You can use it as a customer.